# How to read json file from Asset folder when testing by Espresso?

Tags: android, json, android-espresso

I'm trying to create some fake objects based on .json file. So the architecture of my project looks like this:

```
- MyProject
- app
---- src
-------- androidTest
------------ assets
---------------- FirstObject.json
---------------- SecondObject.json
------------ java
-------- main
-------- test
```

I'm doing testing with Espresso and have some `.json` files under `assets` folder.

My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LocatingActivityTest
{
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<BookingActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(BookingActivity.class);

    private BookingActivity mBookingActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        mBookingActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void viewsMustBeVisible()
    {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab_booking)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));

        mBookingActivity.setTestBooking(BookingTest.getStandardFlight(),
                MyServiceProvider.getServices1(mBookingActivity), // <= Problem
                true,
                MyServiceProvider.getServices2(mBookingActivity), // <= Problem
                MyServiceProvider.getServices3(mBookingActivity)); // <= Problem

        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
        onView(withId(R.id.booking_book_now)).perform(click());

        onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
        onView(withId(R.id.cancel_booking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

The problem is in my `MyServiceProvider` class:

```
public final class MyServiceProvider
{
    public static List<FlightType> getServices1(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("FlightTypes.json");
            String jsonString = read(inputStream);
            Log.e("XXX", "getServices1() => " + jsonString);
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<FlightType>>(){}.getType();
            List<FlightType> flightTypeList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType);

            return flightTypeList;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String read(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        return writer.toString();
    }
.
.
.
}
```

For some reasons `InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("FlightTypes.json");` cannot open the json file and exception throws. This is my log:

```
02-17 21:00:58.984 5686-5706/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: FlightTypes.json
02-17 21:00:58.984 5686-5706/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
02-17 21:00:58.984 5686-5706/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
02-17 21:00:58.984 5686-5706/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
02-17 21:00:58.984 5686-5706/com.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at com.xxx.xxx.utility.MyServiceProvider.getServices1(MyServiceProvider.java:31)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not pass the activity as the context. Instead pass `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` and see if that helps.

Comment: You are awesome... I was thinking my activity might be the problem but didn't know what is its replacement. Thanks...

Comment: Bare in mind that `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()` is the correct choice when you're using assets from `src/androidTest/assets/`. If you want to use assets from `src/main/assets` you should be using `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue, and I found this workaround

```
        boolean thrown = false;
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = mainActivity.getResources().getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("/my/rep/file_name");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            thrown = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertFalse(thrown);
```